# How to display last refresh status of OBIEE Report in Another website?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee, oracle-bi

I have around 20 OBIEE Reports and these Reports automatically refreshed after a certain time period (different for each report). Users navigate to these reports through my SharePoint site home page. Now, I want to display which report is refresh at time in SharePoint page.

Is there any way I can achieve this capability?

Please let me know if requirement is not clear.

Comment: These datestamps should be sitting in the repository somewhere, I'm sure.

Comment: No they are not "sitting in the repository". The RPD is metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you comprehend how OBI and analytical systems work but let me make something clear:

It is NOT the "OBIEE Report" getting refreshed.

First of all because OBI uses "Analyses" whereas BIP uses "Reports".

Second and most importantly it is because the DATA SOURCES are refreshed. The "analysis" is just a visualization container and nothing else. OBIEE does not store or persist data.